# Creating ASCII command strings to send it to COM Port with C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I use RealTerm to write a command to COM port to start a lab equipment.

In the documentation the command is like this format:

```
Command Format
<300,3,1,200,10>
```

So I created a C# desktop with a easy UI program that send the exacly above command to COM port, but the machine doesn't start.

I need help with my C# program.

Thank you guys in advance!

I tryed this code below:

```
if (COMport.IsOpen == true)
{
  // Convert the string into a byte[].
  Data = "<300,3,1,200,10>";
                    
  _mass = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetBytes(Data);                    

  COMport.Write(_mass, 0, _mass.Length);
  COMport.Close();
  return;
}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that I don't need to convert the string to byte.
Are you guys know if when we send a String to COM port the COM port automatically convert the String to ASCii command ?

Comment: there are a couple of things you need to know about your device to establish a working connection. What is the Baudrate? how many stopbits? ir parity on? I advise to read a tutorial. and the manual/documentation of this gadget

Comment: "he COM port automatically convert the String to ASCii command" yes, it can only send bytes. so there is no escape ;)

Comment: COMPort is an Instance of SerialPort? Then try a `COMport.WriteLine(Data);`. Commands are often ended with a NewLine so the system on the other end knows there isn't anything else coming its a complete command. But that should be mentioned in the docs you are refering to and also what kind of NewLine is needed.

Comment: @MongZhu, about the parameters to establish the communication with the equipment in the documentations we have the instruction:

"Controller uses an internal CH340G USB to Serial Converter (set to 9600,8,N,1)"

I put the parameters in my code like that:

SerialPort COMport = new SerialPort(COM4, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One); //Create a new  SerialPort Object (defaullt setting -> 8N1)
 COMport.Open();

In the documentation they require this format code 
<300,3,1,200,10>

But I'm in doubts if we need to put <> in the command or I just need to send the numbers and commas.
Tks

Comment: If you can link to  the doc we might help interpreting it.